# Input string not in correct format or array out of bounds

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In attempting to pass multiple EVAL'ed values as a CommandArgument to a string array in my code behind, I am receiving an error "Input string was not in a correct format".  I am sure it is something easy I overlooked, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Markup:

`<asp:Button ID="DoneButton" runat="server" Text="Done" OnCommand="DoneButton_Click" CommandName="DoneCleanup" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") + ";" +Eval("Date") %>' />`

Code behind:

```
Dim args As String() = New String(1) {}
args = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(";")
MsgBox("passed " & args(0) & " and " & args(1))`
```

If I concatenate my argument in markup with `+` I recieve an error about the input string, if I contatenate with `&` my array doens't fill up (only gets the first index filled).

Comment: What does e.CommandArgument look like when you use & ?

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use QueryString parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Use & to concatenate data as string and then in code-behind don't specify array length, do simple

```
Dim args As String() = e.CommandArgument.Split(";")
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the actual problem was the array not filling and the cause was that (thank you ListView) I was changing my markup on AlternatingItemTemplate and coincidentally testing my change on a button in an ItemTemplate :-/